# Why this exchange

Tags: analysis

I’m reading a book saying that now black Knight at b4 is under attack so need move away.

[image]

However Stockfish app suggests take the white c3 Knight first using f6 Bishop , then black will Rcxc3 take the Bishop, the white can Nc6 move Knight away.

So, is there some reason to do this Bishop-Knight exchange before Nc6? Or I’m not using Stockfish properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The knight is going to have an amazing square on d5 so it's a great idea to trade it before that can happen. Probably an oversight by the author (specially if the book was written before the computer era). Black's position is lost either way so probably not much attention was given to this spot.

Comment: Specifically, after Nd5 followed by Nxf6+, gxf6+ is forced due to the back rank. Add a ruined kingside to the minus pawn. (Yet I'm surprised that it's already +3 after Bxc3.)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann thanks for the explanation. btw "it's already +3 after Bxc3" -- what does "+3" mean?

Comment: @athos He's referring to Stockfish's evaluation

Comment: @HaukeReddmann Maybe "gxf6" is sufficient :)